# How do I open local exe's from within a browser

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser

More specificaly, if I can pass parameters as well this would be ideal. This is for an internal project where a hyperlink will open an exe with parameters

Comment: You won't be able to do this from the Internet Zone without twiddling security settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be a type of active x control... it can be done simply in javascript..

```
<SCRIPT Language="JScript">
function runcmd() {
File="cmd.exe";
WSH=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WSH.run(File);
}
</SCRIPT>
```